# Internet Explorer 9 freezes when debugger is disabled

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools, javascript-debugger

After IE was upgraded from IE8 to IE9, certain page loads in the application I am working on freezes. On keeping the performance manager open, it was observed that there was a memory leak. IE9 simply refused to reclaim the memory after exiting certain javascript functions. But the strange part is that, there is no problem when the debugger is enabled (either by clicking F12 or unchecking the "Disable Script debugging" options in Internet Options -> Advanced). When debugging is enabled, there seemed to be no issues with the page or memory usage. Have anybody experienced this or can help me understand what changes in IE memory usage or the javascript engine internally, with relevance to this issue,  when debugger is enabled ?

Comment: I think you'll need to share a repro/page so that folk can help you more. I work on the debugger and tools for IE and for sure enabling debugging makes a big difference to the memory characteristics of IE9 but typically in the reverse where enabling debugging consumes more memory not less.